# Django models order_by non db field

Tags: django, sql-order-by

I have this model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_id = models.IntegerField()
    foo_old_prize = models.FloatField()
    foo_new_prize = models.FloatField()

def get_dif(self):
    return self.foo_old_prize  - self.foo_new_prize
```

Is there some trick how to do this `Foo.objects.all().order_by('get_dif')` ?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) Django queryset operator:

```
q = Foo.objects.extra(select={'dif': 'foo_old_prize - foo_new_prize'})
q = q.extra(order_by = ['dif'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extra` for this:

```
Foo.objects.extra(
    select={'diff':'foo_old_prize - foo_new_prize'},
    order_by=('diff',)
)
```